# generate ms excel with insert table having merge cells and formulas

Tags: apache-poi

by using Apache poi I can insert table but I have to apply formulas, and merge cells on table columns.

[Example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgOlj.jpg)

This is the requirement to generate excel file

Answer (score 0):

**Merge Cells:**

```
CellRangeAddress address = new CellRangeAddress(firstRow, lastRow, firstColumn, lastColumn);
      sheet.addMergedRegion(address);
```

please note, Indexes are zero based

- Refer Java doc:
  https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#addMergedRegion-org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress-

---

**Add Formula:**

```
String formula= "SUM(A1:A20)";
cell.setCellType(CellType.FORMULA);
cell.setCellFormula(formula);
```

- Refer Java Doc:
  https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellFormula-java.lang.String-